# Regarding variables declared in a C++ file but not the header file

Tags: c++, static, header, global

If I make a static global variable in the C++ file, but do not declare it in the header file, when I make a library from those files, will I be able to access it (the variable)?

Comment: You should really illustrate the context you mean.  I answered the question based on an assumption (_[…time passes…]_ — some assumptions) — and then realized the title uses 'data members' and it isn't clear any more what you mean.

Comment: You're right I edited the title in case someone looks for the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the variable is free-standing and defined at file scope (it is not part of a `class` in some way) and that the keyword `static` adorns its definition, then the variable will be accessible in the file in which it is defined.  It will not be accessible by name from any other file — that's the point (or one of the points) of `static`.  A function in the file with access to it could make it accessible outside the file by returning a pointer or reference to the variable.

Consider putting the variable in the anonymous namespace instead of making it static; that use of static is necessary in C but not necessary in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not be able to access the variable.

Global static variables are [internally linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/internal-linkage?view=vs-2019) meaning they cannot be accessed even from outside that translation unit (file). So you will not even be able to access it inside the library.